# Connectedness and Disconnectedness in General Topology

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Prove or disprove the following:
Are the subspaces $Irr=\Bbb{R}\setminus\Bbb{Q}$ and $\Bbb{Q}$ of the usual topological space $(\Bbb{R}, \mathfrak{T}_{U})$ totally disconnected ?

Comment: It is common to write $\Bbb Q'$ or $\Bbb Q^c$ or $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases the answer is "yes". We will show this by proving that the only connected subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ are singletons. The proof for $\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ is almost the same.

So let $A\subseteq\mathbb{Q}$ be a subset with at least two different points $a,b\in A$, $a<b$. We will show that $A$ is disconnected. Indeed, there exists $r\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ such that $a<r<b$. Note that $r\not\in A$ and therefore $(-\infty, r)\cap A$ and $(r,+\infty)\cap A$ is a decomposition of $A$ into two, nonempty and open subsets. Thus $A$ is not connected.

In order to show the same for $\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ you have to take $r$ from $\mathbb{Q}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$.